# Batch files: how to iterate over a list of symbols?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run the following line of code:

```
for %%i in (+ - * /) do echo %%i
```

But instead of printing the symbols, it prints a weird huge list of files on my computer.

However if I replace the list of symbols by words such as `hi`, it works as expected.

What's going wrong, and how can I iterate through these symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate to the above answer.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('echo + - * /') do @echo %%i
```

Cheer, G

Comment: So what this line does is iterate through every word in the text 'echo + - * /' and echo it, right? If so, why `echo` in the beginning of the text?

Comment: syntax - `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]` see `for /?` in cmd for a detailed explanation. when the (set) in a for loop is surrounded by single quotes `'`, it means it will be interpreted as a command. So, here for loop will iterate through the output of `'echo + - * /'` which is effectively `+ - * /`

Comment: So why not just do `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (+ - * /) do @echo %%i`?

Comment: Its probably due to asterisk `*` symbol is reserved for wildcard search and command prompt does not like it.

Comment: I tried what you said, only I did it like so: `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("+ - * /") do echo %%i`. And it works. Should it not?

Comment: Actually I was wrong. It doesn't work, the output is: `+ - * /` when it should be each symbol on a new line, meaning it thinks the whole text is a single item. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `for /f`. Sample shell script (batch file):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%i in ('echo + - * /') do (
  echo %%i
  echo %%j
  echo %%k
  echo %%l
)
endlocal
```

See `for /?` for more information.

I recommend PowerShell instead:

```
"+-*/".ToCharArray()
```

Comment: I tried what you said, only I did it like so: for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("+ - * /") do echo %%i. And it works. Should it not work?

Comment: See updated answer for how to echo each one on a separate line. As an aside, I would recommend PowerShell instead of cmd.exe shell script (batch).

Answer (score 0):

This will echo characters in a string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=+-*/"
set c=-1
:loop
set /a c+=1
if not "!string:~%c%,1!"=="" echo !string:~%c%,1!&goto :loop
pause
```